# Passing class constructor as parameter to a function expecting a function type

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function of type: `(fooMaker: (_: string) => Foo): void` where `Foo` is a class. Is it possible to pass the `Foo` constructor directly to such a function without having to wrap it like this first: `(s: string) => new Foo(s)`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

Even if `Foo`'s constructor takes just one string argument, it still doesn't mean that in itself, the constructor is assignable to type `(_: string) => Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a wrapper like this:

```js
type ConsToFunc<C extends {new (...args: any[])}>=
    C extends { new (): infer O } ? () => O
    : C extends { new (a: infer A): infer O } ? (A) => O
    : C extends { new (a: infer A, b: infer B): infer O } ? (A, B) => O
    // ...etc
    : never

const consToFunc = <C extends {new (...args: any[]): any}>(c: C): ConsToFunc<C> => 
     (...args: []) => new c(...args)
```

The `ConsToFunc` type maps the constructor to a function type of the same shape and `consToFunc` is the actual wrapper that passes arguments from the outer function down to the constructor.

So in my example this would be used like this: `consToFunc(Foo)`. It's not pretty but it's better than writing the wrapper manually, especially for constructors with several parameters.

Comment: `C extends { new (...args: infer Args): infer O } ? (...args: Args) => O : never` is not working for you?